# Display List of 15 Facebook Friends with Name and Profile Picture in JSP

Tags: eclipse, facebook, jsp

Got a tiny JSP problem. Am new to the whole bit, so please be lenient with me :)
I intend to draw a table with 2 columns: One for facebook friends profiles pictures and the other for facebook friends names.
I've checked a few references on this forum, but they didn't seem to work out.

Here goes the basic code structure:

```
/*
 * @(#)Friends.java 1.0  
 *
 */


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.restfb.Connection;
import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.Parameter;
import com.restfb.exception.FacebookException;



/**
 * Facebook Application Friends Servlet
 * 
 * @version 3.0
 */
public class Friends extends HttpServlet {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private static final int MAX_FRIENDS = 15;

   @Override
   public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

      // set MIME type and encoding
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

      // get writer for output
      final PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();

      // make sure that we have obtained an access token, otherwise redirect
      // to login
      final String accessToken = request.getParameter("access_token");
      if (accessToken == null) {
         response.sendRedirect(Config.getValue("LOGIN_URL"));
         return;
      }

      // get client
      final DefaultFacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);

      // retrieve the document with all friend user ids
      try {
         final Connection<UserWithPicture> friends = client.fetchConnection("me/friends",
               UserWithPicture.class, Parameter.with("fields", "name, picture"),
               Parameter.with("limit", Friends.MAX_FRIENDS));

         p.println( /** Here goes the code for table display **/);
      } catch (final FacebookException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      p.flush();
      p.close();
   }

   @Override
   public void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

      this.doGet(request, response);
   }

}
```

Now, I've written the following code and it's not working for whatever freaky reason there might be. Here it goes:

```
 p.println("<table>" +
            "<c:forEach>" +
                "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + friends.getPicture()
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + friends.name
                    "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
            "</c:forEach>" +
          "</table>");
```

Where the getPicture() method is implemented in the UserWithPicture.java Class:

```
import com.restfb.Facebook;
import com.restfb.types.User;

/**
 * Model class for a User with picture
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class UserWithPicture extends User {

   @Facebook
   private String picture;

   public String getPicture() {

      return this.picture;
   }

}
```

Does anyone see the problem with this code?

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment

Comment: yea - it was one a few weeks ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
 p.println("<table>" +
            "<c:forEach>" +
                "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + friends.getPicture()
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + friends.name
                    "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
            "</c:forEach>" +
          "</table>");
```

you're making a conceptual mistake. You're sending `<c:forEach>` tag plain to the browser. The browser only understands HTML. The browser doesn't understand Java/JSP/JSTL/whatever-server-side tags. When doing this inside a servlet (not recommended), then you need to fix it as follows:

```
p.println("<table>");
for (Friend friend : friends) {
    p.println("<tr><td>" + friend.getPicture() + "</td><td>" + friend.getName() + "</td></tr>");
}
p.println("</table>");
```

Or when doing this inside a JSP, then just write down those tags plain instead of fiddling with *scriptlets*.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${friends}" var="friend">
        <tr><td>${friend.picture}</td><td>${friend.name}</td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is axactly what you are looking for.

http://www.bitspedia.com/2012/01/how-to-get-facebook-friends-list-in.html

The article explains how you can fetch Facebook Friends using java API (RestFB). A sample project is also attached which demonstrate it.